# How to render JS functions in hbs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js

i'm trying to implement google sign in functionality in my website using handlebars.

i want to include my script in a file and load it when the `https://apis.google.com/js/api:client.js?` loads because it creates an object `gapi` which i use in my `js`.

The problem is that handlebars doesn't give any help to load js files.
i tried using helpers but the problem is that `gapi` gets undefined in the registered helper as `gapi` is loaded when client library loads.

i tried doing

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api:client.js?onload=after_load"></script>
<script>
function after_load(){     
{{helper_name gapi}}
}
</script>
```

but still the error persists, is there any way to load a js file in hbs? or i just have to put my code in the script tag itself?

Comment: You DO realize that handlebars is a templating language right? It does not and cannot interact with javascript on the page. As far as handlebars is concerned your script tag is just a string

Comment: So is there any way I could intersex  with Javascript and inject data to my html template as well?  pardon me I'm new to this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my mind you're confusing handlebar with something else.
Instead of doing such things try to do something like this :

- load normally your api in your html.
- once loaded you can call your handlebar part (for example jquery has a nice on ready function).
- after the handlebar result has been processed inject it in your html.
- if you need to launch another script then do it afterwards

Here is one example:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var context = { "form" : "<div class='input-container'><div class='label'>User :</div><div class='input'><input type='text' id='username' name='username'></div></div><div class='input-container'><div class='label'>Password :</div><div class='input'><input type='password' id='password' name='password'></div></div>" };
 var source   = $("#sourceTemplate").html();
  var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
  var html    = template(context);
  $("#resultPlaceholder").html(html);
  alert("Load is done place your additional scripts calls here");
});
```

```css
.input-container { display: inline-block; }
.label { float: left; width: 100px;}
.input { float: left; width: 300px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.5/handlebars.js"></script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api:client.js?onload=after_load"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script id="sourceTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
<div class="container">
  {{{form}}}
</div>
</script>
<br/>
<div id="resultPlaceholder">
</div>
```